# Type-Error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: react-native

How can  I locate the error, is if from the codes on my onboarding screen?, the codes below is from my onboarding.js. how can Ilocate the error from the dot component

```
import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Image, Animated, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
    import {constants, FONTS, SIZES, COLORS } from "../../constants"
    import {TextButton} from "../../assets/components"
const Onboarding = ({ navigation }) => {
  const scrollX = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const flatListRef =React.useRef()
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = React.useState(0)
 const onViewChangeRef = React.useRef(({ viewableItems, changed}) =>{
      setCurrentIndex(viewableItems[0].index)
  })
  const Dots =() => {
    const dotPosition = Animated.divide(scrollX, SIZES.width)
    return(
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems : 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center'
        }}
      >


 {
          constants.onboardingScreens.map((item, index) => {
            const dotColor = dotPosition.interpolate({
              inputRange: [ index-1, index, index +1],
              outputRange: [ COLORS.gray, COLORS.green, COLORS.gray],
              extrapolate: "clamp"
            })

            const dotWidth =  dotPosition.interpolate({
              inputRange: [ index-1, index, index +1],
              outputRange: [10, 10, 10],
              extrapolate: "clamp"
            })

            return (
              <Animated.View
                key={`dot-${index}`}
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 30,
                  marginHorizontal: 6,
                  width: dotWidth,
                  height: 10,
                  backgroundColor: dotColor
                }}
              />
            )
          })
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
  function renderFooter() {
    return(
      <View
        style={{
          height: 120
        }}
      >
```

// pagination & dots

```
        {/* Pagination / Dots */}
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justify Content: 'center',
            }}
        >
          <Dots/>

        </View>

// Buttons

        {/* Buttons */}
        { currentIndex < constants.onboardingScreens.length -1 &&
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              paddingHorizontal: SIZES.padding,
              marginVertical: SIZES.padding
            }}
          >
            <TextButton
              label="Skip"
              buttonContainerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: null
              }}
              labelStyle={{
                color: COLORS.primary
              }}
              onPress={() => navigation.replace("SignIn")}
            />

            <TextButton
              label="Next"
              buttonContainerStyle={{
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                height: 40,
                width: 70,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: COLORS.green,
                borderRadius: 5,       
              }}
              onPress={() => {

                  flatListRef?.current?.scrollToIndex({
                    index: currentIndex + 1,
                    animated: true
                  })
           }}
        />
     </View>
  }
  {currentIndex == constants.onboardingScreens.length -1 &&
    <View
      style={{
        paddingHorizontal: SIZES.padding,
        marginVertical: SIZES.padding,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
      }}
    >
      <TextButton
        label="Get Started"
        buttonContainerStyle={{
          height: 60,
          width: 150,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          height: 50,
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: COLORS.green,
          borderRadius: SIZES.radius
        }}
        onPress={() => navigation.replace("SignIn")}
      />

    </View>
  }
      </View>
    )
  }
      return (
      <View
          style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: COLORS.white
             
          }}
      >
     
          <Animated.FlatList
            ref={flatListRef}
            horizontal
            pagingEnabled
            data={ constants.onboardingScreens }
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            snapToAlignment= "center"
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator ={false}
            onScroll={Animated.event(
              [
                { nativeEvent: { contentOffset:{ x: scrollX} } }
              ],
              { useNativeDriver: false}
              )}
              onViewableItemsChanged={onViewChangeRef.current}
            keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return(
                <View
                style={{
                  width: 20
                }}
             >
```

// Header

```
                {/* Header */}
                <View
                  style={{flex: 3}}
                >
                  <ImageBackground
                    style={{
                      flex: 1,
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "flex-end",
                      height: index == 1 ? "76%" : "100%",
                      width: "100%"
                    }}
                >
                    <Image
                      source={item.bannerImage}
                      resizeMode='contain'
                      style={{
                        width: SIZES.width * 0.8,
                        height: SIZES.width * 0.8,
                        marginBottom: -SIZES.padding
                      }}
                    />

                  </ImageBackground>
                </View>
                      
                 {/* Detail */}
                 <View
                    style={{
                      flex: 1,
                      marginTop: 30,
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      paddingHorizontal: SIZES.radius
                    }}
                 >
                    <Text style={{
                            ...FONTS.h1,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            marginTop: SIZES.radius,
                            color:COLORS.primary 
                          }}
                    >
                           {item.title}
                    </Text>
                    <Text 
                      style={{
                        marginTop: SIZES.radius,
                        textAlign: 'center',
                        paddingHorizontal: SIZES.padding,
                        ...FONTS.body3,
                        color: COLORS.green 
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.description}
                    </Text>

                 </View>
                </View>
              )
            }}
          />

          {renderFooter()}
      </View>
  )
}
export default Onboarding;
```

The code is on onboarding.js and Ive checked all my codes, I cant seem to find where the error is coming from.

Comment: First line of the stack trace is usually most relevant - the error is happening in your Dots component.  Check all the usages of .replace in that component.  If you are still having trouble please post the code of the Dots component - take a look at [ask] when you can.

Comment: I have posted the code please review my question. Thanks

Comment: The only line that uses .replace is `onPress={() => navigation.replace("SignIn")}` - if you comment that line out does the error go away?  If so you have to find where navigation is coming from and make sure it's being passed in properly

Comment: the error is still there, but if I comment <Dots/> the error will go away, and my dots on my onboarding screen wont be visible

Comment: there are actually 2 lines that use .replace - can you try commenting both of them out

Comment: I tried commenting out the two lines that has replace its still giving the error of " cannot read property "replace" of undefined "

Answer (score 0):

1. Give us more information
2. Did you just create a blank react native project?
3. Do you did any changes before the error occurs
4. It looks like you pass null or undefined to component/function which expects a string
5. Maybe you are using a [navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#navigator-dependent-functions) which does not provide replace

Comment: I was working on my sign in screen before this error occured, i cant seem to know where the error is coming from, below is my onbording and sign in screen.

Comment: I have posted the codes on my onboarding.js regarding more information, please review my question.

Comment: Is Onboarding wrapped in an an NavigationContainer?
When does the error occur, when you touch an pressable?

Comment: The skip and next is in a navigation container. The error occured when I started working in my sign in screen, since then I cant continue am stucked there

Comment: What is the navigation container of Onboarding?

Comment: This is what i have on my app.js =  <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false
                }}
                initialRouteName={'Onboarding'}
            >
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Onboarding"
                    component={Onboarding}
                />

Comment: if I comment out <Dots/> from   {/* Pagination / Dots */}
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justify Content: 'center',
            }}
        >
          <Dots/>

        </View> the error will go away, and my dots on my onboarding screen wont be visible